# VMWare vSphere, CentOS7 and customizations

Tags: centos, centos7, vmware-vsphere

I'm running the latest version of esxi (6.5) and vCenter. I created a VM template based on CentOS7, and used a LVM-based disk layout.

However, now vSphere customizations don't work, and I'm getting the following error:

> Customization of the guest operating system 'rhel7_64Guest' is not
>   supported in this configuration. Microsoft Vista (TM) and Linux guests
>   with Logical Volume Manager are supported only for recent ESX host and
>   VMware Tools versions. Refer to vCenter documentation for supported
>   configurations.

The only thing I need to customize, are the ip address and hostname. I don't need to modify any disk sizes.

Is there any way to fix this? I'm already using the latest version of ESX and vSphere. My searches on the Internet reveal lots of out-dated information. Some mention the openvm-deploypkg tool, but It seems that the tool is now integrated with the native open-vm-tools package (source: https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/issues/9).

I cannot understand why customizations can't deal with Linux LVM. I mean, LVM is not a new technology. it's a stable Linux component for many years now, and I'm fond of it. Did VMWare just turn back the clock more than 10 years for me?

Comment: What VM tools version do you have installed in the guest?

Comment: open-vm-tools.x86_64                    10.0.5-2.el7                   @base